# How to use GlueMetaStore with spark.sql in JupyterHub

Tags: apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr, aws-glue, jupyterhub

I want to use the GlueMetaStore with spark.sql.

For that I configured the EMR-Cluster (5.16) and set the following configurations:

```
{
    "Classification":"hive-site",
    "ConfigurationProperties":
    {
        "hive.metastore.client.factory.class":"com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory"
    },
    "Configurations":[]
},
{
    "Classification":"spark-hive-site",
    "ConfigurationProperties":
    {
            "hive.metastore.client.factory.class":"com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory"
    },
    "Configurations":[]
}
```

I used the spark-core to query the databases in JupyterHub, but I just get the default database which is empty. There should be a lot of more database when it works.

Do I need to enbaleHiveSupport or something simular to get the connection working, if yes how can I set it in JupterHub, because the context is already loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

I need to edit "**/etc/livy/conf.dist/livy.conf**" on the masternode 
and add

```
livy.repl.enableHiveContext = true
```

to it.

restart livy-server with:

```
sudo stop livy-server
sudo startlivy-server
```

restart kernel and it works!